# How to match two columns from different Dataframes and with different length?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have already Generated df1 and df2.

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVuJD.png)

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu8N5.png)

Both Dataframes have a common column, `df1[TB_DIV]` and `df2[DIV]`.
I want to generate a new df3 that contains all the info in df1 filtered by all the `df2[DIV]` which are NOT IN df1.

I tried to use the .isin function to filter df1 with the df2 info, but wasn't able to get the expected values.

```
m = DIV_LIST.DIV.isin(DIV_TABLE.TB_DIV)
DIV_LIST1 = DIV_LIST[m]
```

I obtained a empty df3 and in some cases errors due to a length mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going about it like this:

```
df1.loc[df1['TB_DIV'].isin(df2['DIV'])]
```

To get those that are not in, use:

```
df1.loc[~df1['TB_DIV'].isin(df2['DIV'])]
```